# Why does PHP parse some floating point numbers as weird dates?

Tags: php, datetime

Today is 21 September. Why do the following floating point numbers get parsed as weird dates? I realise they're converted to strings first, then parsed, but the format doesn't seem to make any kind of sense. Are these following some format I'm not aware of, or are they undefined behaviour?

I don't see an applicable format on any of:

- [Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php)
- [Date Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)
- [Compound Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)
- [Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

```php
var_dump(new DateTime(5.123456));
```

```
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "3456-09-21 05:12:00.000000"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

> `5.123456`
>
> - hour: `5`
> - minute: `12`
> - second: 0.0
> - year: `3456`
> - month: now (9)
> - day: now (21)

```php
var_dump(new DateTime(5.1203047891));
```

```
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "7891-09-21 05:12:00.000000"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

> `5.1203047891`
>
> - hour: `5`
> - minute: `12`
> - second: 0.0
> - **ignored:** `0304`
> - year: `7891`
> - month: now (9)
> - day: now (21)

Some other strings:

- '5': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.1': `2019-09-21 05:01:00.000000` 5:01 am, 2019-09-21 (today)
- '5.12': `2019-09-21 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 2019-09-21 (today)
- '5.123': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.1234': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.12345': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.123456': `3456-09-21 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 3456-09-21
- '5.1234567': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.12345678': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.123456789': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.1234567891': `7891-09-21 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 7891-09-21
- '5.12345678912': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.123456789123': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.1234567891234': `7891-08-22 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 7891-08-22
- '5.12345678912345': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.123456789123456': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.1234567891234567': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.12345678912345678': `5678-08-22 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 5678-08-22
- '5.123456789123456789': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.12345678901234567': `4567-05-03 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 4567-05-03
- '5.1234567890**001**4567': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.1234567890**002**4567': `Failed to parse time string`
- '5.1234567890**003**4567': `4567-01-03 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 4567-01-03 (3rd day of the year)
- '5.1234567890**365**4567': `4567-12-31 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 4567-12-31 (365th day of the year)
- '5.1234567890**366**4567': `4568-01-01 05:12:00.000000` 5:12 am, 4568-01-01 (366th day(!) of a non-leap year)
- '5.1234567890**367**4567': `Failed to parse time string`

I've been able to predict certain parts, but it doesn't seen to follow a sensible overall format. What's going on here?

Comment: 08-22 is 234th day of year

Comment: 05-03 is 123rd day https://www.scp.byu.edu/docs/doychart.html

Comment: Those were ones you didn't put in, so I thought it would help. The ones that fail to parse probably don't have a valid day of year where it's looking for them.

Comment: I think we have to have a look on `Date API` for `php`

Comment: PHP doesn't document the date formats in detail, you'll probably have to read the parser source code.

Comment: @Barmar The function (not the entire class) that parses the date is 24000 lines long!

Comment: My guess is that whatever this is doing isn't really intentional, it may just be the side effects of some heuristics in the code.

Comment: @Barmar that's my guess too. Hopefully someone knows for sure!

Comment: Why does it matter? Do you really need to parse floating point numbers as dates and get predictable results? This seems like just random trivia you stumbled onto by accident, and will never come up in practice.

Comment: @Barmar Because if I submit a patch to fix this assumed bug, I could break people's production code.

Answer (score 1):

Only the creator of the DateTime class code can fully answer the question. I'm just trying to explain the motivation. DateTime wants to interpret many of the possible free formats. First, the input is converted to a string.

```
class test{
  public function __toString(){
    return "2001-02-03 04:05:06";
  }
}

$d = new DateTime(new test);
//object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2001-02-03 04:05:06" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }
```

The method __toString used here confirms this.
If the string is empty then a date is generated from the current day and the current time. This is also the basis for missing information from the input. Then tries to recognize a time ([Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php)).

This test shows that the first attempt is to determine a time.
Look at the following tests ror a confirmation.
This is described in the manual [Date Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php):

**Year (and just the year)  YY  "1978", "2008"**

'1978' can not be time, so it is parsed as a year.

```
var_dump(new DateTime('1978'));  //"1978-09-23 09:46:43.000000"
```

But '2008' can represent a time. It is parsed as time 20:08.

```
var_dump(new DateTime('2008'));  //  "2019-09-23 20:08:00.000000"
```

The hours, minutes and seconds can be changed by:,,. or nothing to be separated.
If only one time is detected, then the current day is taken as date.
Examples (Today is 23 Sep 2019):

```
'04:08','0408','04.08'      => "2019-09-23 04:08:00.000000"
'04.08.05','04.08:05','040805'  => "2019-09-23 04:08:05.000000"
```

Then the date is tried to parse. The order Date / Time or Time Date in the Input does not matter. All strings parse to "2001-02-03 04:05:00.000000":

```
'04:05 2001-02-03'
'04.05 20010203'
'04.0520010203'
'4.0520010203'

'2001020304.05'
'20010203 04.05'
```

Your String: '5.123456'

The parser first analyzes 5.12 as time 05:12. The Rest is '3456' the year.

The String '5.12345678901232004' will parsed as '5.12 34567890123 2004'
5.12 as time 05:12 and 2004 as year.

```
var_dump(new DateTime('5.12 34567890123 2004'));
//object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2004-05-02 05:12:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }
```

I have no idea how to determine the remaining string '34567890123' day 02 and month 05.

The question was not answered completely. I hope to have contributed to the understanding of the DateTime parser.